Is it possible to modify (monkey patch) internals function of a function imported in an imported function in javascript?
Is it possible to modify the behavior of functions called inside a closure in js?
Lets say i have this code which i am importing from a library:
// b.js
export const b = () => { 
  console.log('b') 
}

// t.js
import {b} from 'b.js';
export const t = () => { 
  const c = b;
  c();
}

And inside my code i want to modify the behaviour of b, so that i can modify the functionality of the code.

import {t} from 't.js';

// Code that modifies b
t();


Of course this is a very abstract example, what i actually want to do is extend the functionality of web-vitals.
The motivation is to be able to extend onLCP to track custom elements which use element timings.

...the shortest possible answer about modifying something in a closure is no. How exactly are you trying to change the behavior of LCP tracking...and also why?

Okey, no is a valid answer. I was playing with the Proxy API but nothing seems to work which makes sense.

Note that nothing is being closed over in this code. t() looks up the current value of b every time it's called, it doesn't save the original value of b from definition time.

@JaredSmith Well the general idea as that i am trying to make custom LCPs.
If a loading spiner is the biggest element i should be able to triggure a new event using element timings.
But the reason why i was hoping to modify the behaviour instead of implement my own is that i load the code dynamically from there cdn and this would prevent me from causing code to be duplicated.
I know its not the correct solution but ...

@Barmar I see what you mean, b is actually just a local var, so this is not really a closure as such. How can i reformulate my question then?

It would be different if it were something like export const t = ((c) => () => c())(b);. That uses an IIFE to snapshot the imported value of b.
